# Обрезается изображение в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка

Обрезается svg в WordPresse. Изначально, при формировании сайта параметры ширины были меньше тех, что сейчас, и есть подозрение что проблема именно в этом. Но никак не могу найти кусок кода, который его обрезает.
Ниже изображения:

1. Вид в ВордПрессе
2. Вид в просмотре svg

[image: Как обрезается картинка в WP]
[image: Как обрезается картинка в WP]

Comment: Вы для загрузки svg устанавливали какой-то плагин, по типу safe svg или просто добавляли mime type в functions.php? Я чего спрашиваю, потому что вообще svg как таковые в WordPress не кропаются, как прочие форматы изображений при использовании `add_image_size();`

Answer (score 0):

Мне чёт кажется, что ваш SVG без значения атрибута viewBox, а если он удален (например при минимизации), то браузер сам решает как засовывать картинку в тег img потому так и обрезается